# C Void Pointer Inquiry - Don't get why my code is not working as I intended :(

Tags: c, pointers

Can anyone please explain to me why printf("%d\n", (int *)p[0]) does not print 10?

```
void *p[10] = {NULL};
int a = 10;
p[0] = &a;
printf("%d\n", (int *)p[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are interpreting the pointer in the array as a pointer to int (`(int *)p[0]`), but not dereferencing it, so instead do `*(int *)p[0]`

Comment: yep sorry, my fault

Answer (score 1):

The argument corresponding to `%d` has to be an `int`, but `p[0]` is a pointer, not an `int`. You need to dereference it using the `*` operator.

```
printf("%d\n", *(int *)p[0]);
```